# How to use minmax func to limit amount of columns

Tags: css, frontend, css-grid

I'm trying to create a responsive grid design with css-grid. I want to have columns that are about 400px and can expand to 500px. When a grid cell can no longer occupy its space, I want it to wrap. Essentially, on small viewports, I want a column of one while on bigger viewports, I want a max of 2 columns. Is there a way of doing this without media queries? I'm trying to avoid this since I have a sidebar that can expand which does not alter the view width.

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  /* below line DOES NOT WORK */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(minmax(1, 2), minmax(400, 500));
}
```

Comment: I think you could either move your answer to a self-answer and mark it correct; or, mark the given answer as correct if it was useful (i.e. likely to be the answer for other people coming here with a question similar to yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Grid auto-fill with max-width

You can **not** do minmax and then minmax on the repeat.

The repeat is the first tell how many times repeat, and the seconed for what to repeat.

Use auto-fill give you min width.

`grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(400px,1fr));`

and you can tell the `.grid-wrapper` for example `max-width: 1000px;`

Like that you have some way to control the grid.

I gave a brief explanation here, however, I did not exactly understand your explanation - what your table looks like.

Comment: Sorry about my description, I'll edit it and include my answer. Thanks you your help, it pushed me in the right direction!

Comment: While I don't know how to account for columns expanding to 500px from 400px, I have a way to limit the number of columns using width and max-width which is what I was really seeking.

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 500px);
  max-width: 1000px; /* prevents more than 2 columns */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Auto-fill here will let the browser decide how many columns can exist in the given width. Considering max-width is set to 1000px, 2 500px columns can only exist at view widths greater than or equal to 1000px. Thank you Omer!